# ¿Cómo realizar backup de bases de datos MySQL muy pesadas?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, myisam

Necesito realizar un backup para una base de datos muy pesada (aproximadamente de 30GB). Quisiera saber si existe otro método aparte de realizarlo por la interfaz gráfica de phpMyAdmin o mediante un `dump`.

Comment: Con que motor de almacenamiento funciona tu base de datos?

Comment: el motor es mysam

Comment: Hola, Juan Maldonado , por la experiencia que he tenido usando phpMyAdmin y mysql, la mejor forma lejos es usar la linea de comandos ya que phpMyAdmin siempre trae problemas con los tamaños de los archivos que vas a exportar o importar.  [Documentacion Mysql dump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html)

Comment: Se puede comprimir la base de datos con el 7z.