# ¿Cómo hacer backup de una base de datos con tablas muy grandes? InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Tengo una base de datos **`MySQL`** con el motor **`InnoDB`**, la cual, algunas tablas son muy grandes (aproximadamente unos **30GB** cada una).

A la hora de hacer un `Backup` o un `Restore` de esas tablas de la `Base de Datos`, tengo el problema de que tarda mucho tiempo en restaurar la copia usando archivos `Dump`.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder realizar los `Backups` y los `Restores` de esas tablas de forma muy rápida?

---

**NOTA:**

Ésta pregunta viene referenciada de la [siguiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131392/c%C3%B3mo-realizar-backup-de-bases-de-datos-mysql-muy-pesadas), pero con otro motor de almacenamiento de base de datos.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**`InnoDB`** a diferencia de otros motores, tiene una opción de poder activar o desactivar la característica de tener un archivo por tabla ([File-Per-Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)), la cual, nos facilita el poder hacer `Backups` y `Restores` de unas tablas específicas.

Para activar `File-Per-Table` hay que modificar el archivo de configuración de `MySQL` y añadir en la etiqueta `[mysqld]` lo siguiente:

> innodb_file_per_table=1

Para activar la opción habrá que reiniciar el servicio MySQL una vez modificado el archivo de configuración.

Para realizar un `Backup` y un `Restore` rápido, vamos a aprovecharnos de la funcionalidad que tiene `InnoDB` para poder descartar e importar los diferentes `Tablespaces` de la base de datos.

> **Para los ejemplos a continuación vamos a suponer que los archivos de mi Base de Datos se encuentran en `'C:\BD\'` y la carpeta donde dejo
>   la copia de seguridad es `'C:\Copia\'`.**

**Procedimiento Backup:**

El primer paso que debemos hacer para realizar un `Backup` es bloquear la tabla para poder manipular los archivos correctamente:

`FLUSH TABLES DB1.Tabla1 FOR EXPORT`

Ahora iremos a buscar los archivos de la tabla que hemos bloqueado (`'C:\BD\Tabla1.*'`) y los copiaremos a la carpeta donde dejamos la copia de seguridad (`'C:\Copia\'`).

Una vez copiados los archivos, desbloquearemos la tabla que hemos bloqueado anteriormente:

`UNLOCK TABLES;`

---

**Procedimiento Restore:**

El primer paso que debemos hacer es descartar el `Tablespace` de la tabla que vamos a restaurar:

`ALTER TABLE DB1.Tabla1 DISCARD TABLESPACE;`

De esta manera la tabla ya no está vinculada a la `Base de datos` y ya puedes manipular los archivos relacionados con esa tabla.

Ahora iremos a buscar los archivos de `Backup` de la tabla que hemos descartado (`'C:\Copia\Tabla1.*'`) y los copiaremos en la carpeta donde están los archivos de la tabla de la `Base de datos` (`'C:\BD\'`), reemplazando todos los archivos.

Una vez copiados los archivos importaremos el `Tablespace` de la tabla y, de esta manera, habremos restaurado la copia que teníamos a la Base de Datos:

`ALTER TABLE DB1.Tabla1 IMPORT TABLESPACE;`

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que uses cualquiera de estas dos herramientas:

- [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/index.html): Es una herramienta de Percona, hace respaldos completos e incrementales sin bloqueos, es consistente y restaura muy rápido, solo compatible con InnoDB. Básicamente hace una copia de las tablas directamente del file system y no es un .sql y por eso es más rápido.
- [mydumper](https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper): Esta herramienta permite hacer respaldos y restaurar usando el paralelismo (multuples cores) para incrementar la velocidad, es consistente y fácil de usar, este tipo de respaldo genera muchos .sql.